# Java FileWriter add column to csv

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

I'm writing a couple of arrays to a CSV and I have a problem creating a 2nd column.

I can write the first column no problem. When I try to append to the 2nd column it writers to the 2nd column but at the end of the first column.

```
  public void printCSV() throws IOException{

    // file writer
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file path");


    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

    if(myArray[0][i] == null){
        writer.append(" ");
    }else{

        writer.append(myArray[0][i]);
        writer.append("\n");    
    }


        } // end of for loop



    for(int i = 0; i < emptyResults.length; i++){

        writer.append(",");
        writer.append(String.valueOf(emptyResults[i]));
        writer.append("\n");


    }

    writer.close();

}
```

Example output:

```
                   column1 column2
                    entry1
                    entry2
                    entry3
                    entry4
                            entry1  
                            entry2  
                            entry3
```

what I'd like:

```
                    column1 column2
                    entry1  entry1
                    entry2  entry2
                    entry3  entry3
```

When I write the 2nd array to the csv I force the write to another column using the "," but it won't start writing at row 1.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Solution: A single loop with a new line with every loop.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++){

    if(myArray[0][i] == null){
        writer.append(" ");
    }else{

        writer.append("\n");
        writer.append(myArray[0][i]+","+emptyResults[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Use a single loop and write both values from the arrays in one line.

Comment: @Tharun I'll give that a shot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from your code &  explanation i am assuming that both arrays will be of same size.Try this

```
public void printCSV() throws IOException{

    // file writer
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");



    for(int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length && i < emptyResults.length; i++){


    if(myArray[0][i] == null){
        writer.append(" "+String.valueOf(emptyResults[i]));
    }else{

        writer.append(myArray[0][i]+" "+String.valueOf(emptyResults[i]));
        writer.append("\n");    
    }


        } // end of for loop
    writer.close();

}
```